# Turn an ArtPro file into a PDF using Automator

Tags: pdf, applescript, action, automator, file-conversion

I am attempting to use Automator to turn a folder of ArtPro (.ap) images into .pdf's, but I can't find any existing or downloadable actions to do anything other than open a .ap file with automator.

Does anyone know of an action I could download or a different way to automate the conversion of .ap to .pdf? Is it possible to do it using applescript instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible with ArtPro itself (manually) or **Automation Engine**'s **Action List**. You can try recording your actions with "Watch-me-do" in Automator, but it's not a good idea. Apple Script will not help.

The problem is that Esko has its own file format which no other software can understand.

Answer (score 1):

I could see some approaches:

a) open the document in ArtPro, then use the Print command and write out as PDF

b) (if Preview.app can read in .ap files) open the document in Preview.app and save as PDF

c) if there is no direct way (a) or b)), write out as TIFF and convert that intermediate file, for example in Acrobat or Preview

Comment: Thanks for the advice
I thought the first idea was really clever, but although it makes perfect sense it doesn't work for some reason, it doesn't come up with errors it just doesn't print it out as a pdf.
With the second idea I tried opening it with preview.app both in and out of automator but neither worked, .ap files are horrible.

How would I go about writing out the file as a .tiff? When you say in acrobat or preview are you talking about using them to open the .ap file? .ap files aren't compatible with either of those unfortunately..

Comment: In my point c) I referred to Acrobat or Preview to open the intermediate file (for example the TIFF). Not knowing ArtPro, I dont know about the export capabilities, but if you can export as TIFF, for example, you then can open this TIFF in Acrobat or Preview and write out a PDF.

Comment: That make sense, but wouldn't I need to automate ArtPro to export as a TIFF first? Like I said unfortunately automator has no actions for ArtPro so all I can do is open it. It's looking like what I'm trying to code isn't possible in automator..  Do you think it might be possible in AppleScript instead?

Answer (score 0):

The ArtPro format is proprietary to Esko - you won't be able to open it in anything else.

Secondly, Esko favours selling its own automation solution (Automation Engine) - ArtPro will not allow you to automate it. It doesn't integrate with Automator and as far as I know it also doesn't publish AppleScript actions.

So basically I think your only option is using Automation Engine from Esko.

Answer (score 0):

You need used task "Export ArtPro to Normalized PDF File" in esko automation engine